# Remove every row in every table that contains a userid column

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have inherited a large database complete with user data and want to know if it is possible to strip out all the user data except the one admin user in order to redeploy for a new project.

I'm looking for something like:

DELETE FROM all_tables.all_rows WHERE row contains column userid AND userid != admin_user_id

Bonus points if you can also make it work for the odd table where instead of "userid" they use "user" or "loggedin" as the column name.

My database is in postgresql but I'm guessing straightforward SQL will do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this with plain sql.
First, you need to find these tables and column names:

```
SELECT table_name, column_name from information_schema.columns
where column_name in ('userid ', 'user');
```

Than you create plpgsql function, which iterates over these data, build necessary delete query string and executes as dynamic query:

```
execute 'delete from ' || x.table_name || ' where ' ...
```

Comment: I can understand your first statement and I can see how that would give me the relevant tables, but I'm a total novice to postgresql and can't test you solution yet I'm afraid

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "DELETE * FROM table WHERE EXISTS table.userid LIKE '%' AND table.userid != table.admin_user_id";

$query = "DELETE * FROM table WHERE EXISTS table.user LIKE '%' AND table.user != table.admin_user_id";

$query = "DELETE * FROM table WHERE EXISTS table.loggedin LIKE '%' AND table.loggedin != table.admin_user_id";
```

you may need to use <> instead of != in POSTgresql, i don't know.
Untested, please test first.

Comment: one at a time, you can only run on query at a time.

Comment: And only on one table at a time I think... My aim is to run this on the whole database in one go.

Comment: Ok fair enough, but i'm pretty sure you can't do this in one query, are you running this on your database manager or through php? If you are running on a database manager, it might be worth setting up a script to do this for you.